# Define unknown type Javascript function in Typescript definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am attempting to include when.js (a public Promise library on github that can be found [here](https://github.com/cujojs/when)) as a property of Cesium (a public 3-D modelling framework described [here](https://cesiumjs.org)) in a Typescript definition file I have for the Cesium library. This is because I am trying to convert some Javascript files from a project that utilizes Cesium to Typescript, and the Cesium.js code that is referenced has the below code snippet included. I am at a loss at how to declare when.js in the d.ts file, however. It doesn't appear to be a class, and I don't think it's an interface. How should I go about this property - what kind of object is it?

```
(function(define) { 'use strict';
define('ThirdParty/when',[],function () {
var reduceArray, slice, undef;

//
// Public API
//

when.defer     = defer;     // Create a deferred
/* more when.otherProperties set here */

/**
 * Register an observer for a promise or immediate value.
 *
 * @param {*} promiseOrValue
 * @param {function?} [onFulfilled]
 * @param {function?} [onRejected]
 * @param {function?} [onProgress]
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function when(promiseOrValue, onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress) {
    // Get a trusted promise for the input promiseOrValue, and then
    // register promise handlers
    return resolve(promiseOrValue).then(onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress);
}

/**
 * @param {*} promiseOrValue the rejected value of the returned {@link Promise}
 * @returns {Promise} rejected {@link Promise}
 */
function reject(promiseOrValue) {
    return when(promiseOrValue, rejected);
}
/* more functions defined here, including a 'defer' function */
```

Example code referencing this:

```
static getData(/* vars */) {
    /* stuff */
    return Cesium.when.reject('message here');
}
```

Currently I can get the above code to work if I declare a class called "when" in the Cesium.d.ts file I have. The only problem is that in this case "when" is a constructor, but as is clearly defined in the code snippet, the function "when" returns a Promise.

What I tried that worked (in the sense that it compiles and runs. probably breaks some Typescript-lovers' hearts):

```
declare module Cesium {
    /* a lot of other functions, classes, interfaces, enums... */
    class when extends Promise<any> {
        constructor(promiseOrValue: any, onFulfilled?: Function, onRejected?: Function, onProgress?: Function);
        static reject(promiseOrValue: any): Promise<any>;
    }
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

After having poked around a little more on Typescript documentation, I'm getting convinced that what I need is a [hybrid type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types). But as it's declared as an interface the TS compiler doesn't recognize it as a property of Cesium.

Here's what I tried:

```
interface when {
  (promiseOrValue: any, onFulfilled?: Function, onRejected?: Function, onProgress?: Function): any
  reject(promiseOrvalue: any): any;
```

}

This results in the following error at compile time:

```
TS2339: Property 'when' does not exist on type 'typeof Cesium'.
```

Comment: What is getting exported exactly?

Comment: The Cesium library. It includes this third-party "when.js" in it. Originally I downloaded a Cesium.d.ts file available online (https://gist.github.com/mgiraldo/f07432df1ccc50a0ea6e), but it isn't defined in this definition file.

Answer (score 0):

I see their `warn.js` contains JSDoc comments with types.

You should try this tool:

https://github.com/ConquestArrow/dtsmake

To make .d.ts files automatically. It supports JSDoc annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was aware that such tools exist; however I'd like to know how to write them myself before depending on a tool. Also, the recent build for the above tool is failing..